# StackTraceElement getFileName() gives null on lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a custom logging system that for each logging statement shows what filename and linenumber the logging statement is.
This works for great, except for lambdas. The StackTraceElement that corresponds to the location inside the lambda, doesn't produce a filename. This probably has something to do with the JVM generating some sort of code to make lambdas work, I'm not sure. Is there a way to get the filename and line number somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name of the source file where the lambda was used (earlier in the stacktrace), but since lambdas get compiled to inner classes, they have no actual source file name.

They don't have line numbers either, since the line number would be in a class that you can't see (the generated inner class).

Comment: It is disappointing that the JVM doesn't carry over the line number and file name information in the runtime generation of the lambda bytecodes. It makes me want to avoid lambdas, as suave as they may seem. Besides, they're confusing to a lot of people looking at the code for the first time. It's kind of like operator overloading, where you can't trust the code unless you become aware of where all the code is coming from. This tucked away information isn't following the original spirit behind Java in my opinion.
Changing to anonymous inner class makes it more readable and debuggable.

Comment: @Mike See my edit. Also don't use lambdas just because you can. I've had to tell my co-workers not to use lambdas in places where it's not warranted. Just because there's a new trick in Java doesn't mean you need to go overboard with it.

Comment: After searching for if others including company policies, might have evolved into also avoid lambdas, and only use them when actually warranted, I landed back to my own message. I've grown more anti-lambda debugging my own code. In theory, the compiler *could* have generated an anonymous inner class I think, but it's going this static-class-on-the-side route. Why exactly I'm not sure. Might have to do with capturing variables outside the lambda. I knew lambdas were trouble the moment I saw them. It's a like a bad artist forcing their art. Java is supposed to be team development proof...